# Poll System in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to Display Polling in section of My Page, I have created these POCO classes for do that :

```
public class Polls
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public IList<PollOptions> PollOptions { get; set; }
}

public class PollOptions
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Polls Polls { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public int Votes { get; set; }
}
```

And I have Used below ViewModel :

```
public class PollViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I passed my model using above ViewModel to my View :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var poll = from p in db.Polls
               join po in db.PollOptions on p.Id equals po.Polls.Id
               where p.Active == true
               select new PollViewModel { 
                   Id=p.Id,
                   Question=p.Question,
                   Answer=po.Answer
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

in my View I want to display `Question` and `Answer` of my Poll, I have tried this code :

```
@section Polling{
    @foreach (var item in Model.Polls)
    {
        <input type="radio" /> @item.Answer
    }
}
```

above code works correctly but I want to display `Question` too, something like this :

```
@section Polling{
    **@Model.Polls.Question**
    @foreach (var item in Model.Polls)
    {
        <input type="radio" /> @item.Answer
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

**PS: I have one row in my Polls Table for display in Home Page**

Comment: hi mr Sirwan Afifi  You can help me  by Graphic View Poll   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661924/display-polling-result-poll-with-chart-showing-graphic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is relationship between Polls and PollsOption. So get Polls from your db. And pass it to view. Also you already have PollsOptions that connected to to their Polls. No need to join two tables.

controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // get active Polls
    var poll = from p in db.Poll
               where p.Active == true
               select p;

    // pass it to the view
    return View(poll);
}
```

view

```
@model IEnumerable<Polls>

@section Polling{
    @foreach (var question in Model)
    {
        <h2>@question.Question</h2>
        @foreach(var answer in question.PollOptions)
        {
            <input type="radio" /> @answer.Answer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx, but I have received Null Exception in this line foreach (var answer in question.PollOptions)

Comment: Is not there relationship between your classes? Is there any Polls that have no PollOptions?

Comment: @Sirwan Afifi, try eager loading of related poll options: var pollsList = db.Poll.Include(x=>x.PollOptions).where(x=>x.IsActive).ToList(); now pollList includes PollOptions as well.